# How to pass anyType arguments in Python Suds?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I have this SOAP function definition (provided by SUDS):

```
getPaths(xs:anyType[] accessions, xs:string clientType, )
```

In the WSDL, the inputs look like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="getPaths">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="accessions" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="clientType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I tried to call it like this in a Python program:

```
result = client.service.getPaths([“string1”, “string2”], "string3")
```

Get this fault:

```
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'com.xyz.SomeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String'
```

I think I am not provide the data for anyType incorrectly. I cannot find any documentation or information from the web on how to specify anyType data. I am assuming I can pass any types. The server side is working fine cause there are happy Java clients.

Thanks for your help in advance.